# PHP Google App Engine YAML not finding directories

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, app.yaml

My App Engine isn't loading my css, javascripts, or images. My index.php and login.php are the only files that I've been able to find so far however my other files use sessions to prevent unauthorized access so I'm not sure I'll be able to get to them without logging in first.

Directory Structure is from the app.yaml file to the corresponding files.

I'm using Google's App Engine with PHP and my YAML code is below

```
handlers:
- url: /index.php
  script: content/home/index.php

- url: /login.php
  script: content/home/login.php

- url: /control.php
  script: content/home/control.php

- url: /admin.php
  script: content/home/admin.php

- url: /logout.php
  script: content/home/logout.php

- url: /checkaccess.php
  script: content/home/checkaccess.php

- url: /register.php
  script: content/home/register.php

- url: /managemodule.php
  script: content/home/managemodule.php

- url: /manageuser.php
  script: content/home/manageuser.php

- url: /update.php
  script: content/home/update.php

- url: /.*
  script: content/home/index.php

- url: /images
  script: images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: system/templates/stylesheets

- url: /includes
  script: system/templates/includes

- url: /scripts
  script: system/templates/javascript
```

I tried to use static_dir: as well as script: for the stylesheets, javascript, and images. The includes oddly enough works fine with no issues but I cannot get my images, css, or scripts to work correctly.

I tried to inspect the files and they're not found but I know they've uploaded via appcfg.py. In my logs it states "No handlers matched this URL."

If anyone has a great readme or any other information regarding YAML I'd greatly appreciate it. I've read the YAML description from Google a few times and checked the YAML website I feel like I'm doing it right. I tried with another project (a lot simpler) and it worked with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
handlers:
- url: /index.php
  script: index.php

- url: /login.php
  script: login.php

- url: /control.php
  script: control.php

- url: /admin.php
  script: admin.php

- url: /logout.php
  script: logout.php

- url: /checkaccess.php
  script: checkaccess.php

- url: /register.php
  script: register.php

- url: /managemodule.php
  script: managemodule.php

- url: /manageuser.php
  script: manageuser.php

- url: /update.php
  script: update.php

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /includes
  script: system/templates/includes

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts
```

Ended up working but I wouldn't be surprised if I have more errors still. Just put this up in case someone else stumbles upon this. What was wrong was the /.* that I had above. I removed that and put the static_dir and it worked...

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is one of the unfortunate features that's missing in beta PHP GAE.

Comment: if I hadn't already upvoted this answer the last time I was deploying a GAE app, I would upvote it again!